# android webview probleme loading video

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, vimeo

I am creating an android app.
Webview with a webpage including videos. 
I am not able to start these videos this is my Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {    
@SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi" }) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    String url = "http://www.___.com/";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); 
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()   
        {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    return false;
                }
            });
    view.loadUrl(url); 
}
```

When I start a video it remains loading but never shows content.

Comment: How are you displaying the video on your webpage?

Comment: i just take a link that contains videos and highlights as you can see in my code i load a url and inside this url there is some videos but i can't start them

Comment: Yes, but how are you showing them on your webpage (not webview)? Do you use a loader? HTML5? Do the videos load in a standard browser just fine?

Comment: it's not my webpage, its just a page including video i'll give you example : http://www.soccerhighlightstoday.com/